# Host TreeView in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I want to create a TreeView column for a DataGridView. I have followed the example in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) by extending the TreeView as below.

```
public class TreeViewEditingControl : TreeView, IDataGridViewEditingControl

public class TreeViewCell : DataGridViewComboBoxCell // Not sure whether this should be DataGridViewTextBoxCell
```

This is my issue. I can see the Treeview in cells, but I don't know how to increase the height of the Cell/TreeView when user click on a cell (as ComboBox expands). Does anyone have any idea on this?

Comment: +1 for creativity.  Never thought of putting a TreeCtrl in a DataGridView before.  Nice work!

Comment: // Not sure whether this should be DataGridViewTextBoxCell - Yes, this should be DataGridViewTextBoxCell if you are only going to show a Text value when the Cell is just being viewed.  I imagine you'll want the treeView to show up only when a user clicks the cell for editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would spawn a new borderless form with a TreeCtrl Docked inside, I've done this with a CalendarControl and it works well.  The user will not know the difference if you set the upper left hand corner of the form to the upper left hand corner of the cell that is being edited.  Hope this is what you are looking for.

**Edit:**

Here is an implementation I did for a File Selection Cell.  It has a Browse button that appears in the cell when you click it for editing and it opens a FileOpenDialog.  The code is lengthy, but I think you can pick out the parts you need to implement.

```
public class DataGridViewFileColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
    public DataGridViewFileColumn() : base(new DataGridViewFileCell())
    {
        BrowseLabel = "...";
        SaveFullPath = false;
    }

    public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            return base.CellTemplate;
        }
        set
        {
            // Ensure that the cell used for the template is a DataGridViewFileCell.
            if (value != null &&
                !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(DataGridViewFileCell)))
            {
                throw new InvalidCastException("Must be a DataGridViewFileCell");
            }
            base.CellTemplate = value;
        }
    }

    [Description("Label to place on Browse button"),Category("Appearance")]
    [DefaultValue("...")]
    public string BrowseLabel 
    {
        get; 
        set; 
    }

    [Description("Save full path name"), Category("Behavior")]
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool SaveFullPath
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}


public class DataGridViewFileCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    public DataGridViewFileCell() : base()
    {
    }

    public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object
            initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        // Set the value of the editing control to the current cell value.
        base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue,
            dataGridViewCellStyle);
        FileEditingControl ctl = (FileEditingControl)DataGridView.EditingControl;
        // Use the default row value when Value property is null.
        if (this.Value == null)
        {
            ctl.Filename = this.DefaultNewRowValue.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            ctl.Filename = this.Value.ToString();
        }
    }

    public override Type EditType
    {
        get
        {
            // Return the type of the editing control that DataGridViewFileCell uses.
            return typeof(FileEditingControl);
        }
    }

    public override Type ValueType
    {
        get
        {
            // Return the type of the value that DataGridViewFileCell contains.
            return typeof(string);
        }
    }
}

class FileEditingControl : FileTextBox, IDataGridViewEditingControl
{
    DataGridView dataGridView;
    private bool valueChanged = false;
    int rowIndex;

    public FileEditingControl()
    {
    }

    #region IDataGridViewEditingControl implementations
    public object EditingControlFormattedValue
    {
        get
        {
            return Filename;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value is String)
            {
                try
                {
                    Filename = (String)value;
                }
                catch
                {
                    Filename = value.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public object GetEditingControlFormattedValue(
        DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
    {
        return EditingControlFormattedValue;
    }

    public void ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(
        DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        this.Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font;
    }

    public int EditingControlRowIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return rowIndex;
        }
        set
        {
            rowIndex = value;
        }
    }

    public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(
        Keys key, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
    {
        switch (key & Keys.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Left:
            case Keys.Up:
            case Keys.Down:
            case Keys.Right:
            case Keys.Home:
            case Keys.End:
            case Keys.PageDown:
            case Keys.PageUp:
                return true;
            default:
                return !dataGridViewWantsInputKey;
        }
    }

    public void PrepareEditingControlForEdit(bool selectAll)
    {
    }

    public bool RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public DataGridView EditingControlDataGridView
    {
        get
        {
            return dataGridView;
        }
        set
        {
            dataGridView = value;
        }
    }

    public bool EditingControlValueChanged
    {
        get
        {
            return valueChanged;
        }
        set
        {
            valueChanged = value;
        }
    }

    public Cursor EditingPanelCursor
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Cursor;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    protected override void OnValueChanged(FileEventArgs eventargs)
    {
        // Notify the DataGridView that the contents of the cell
        // have changed.
        valueChanged = true;
        this.EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
        base.OnValueChanged(eventargs);
    }
}

public partial class FileTextBox : UserControl
{

    #region Constructors
    public FileTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Tooltip = new ToolTip();

        SaveFullPath = false;
        AllowMultipleFiles = false;
        BrowseLabel = "...";
    }
    #endregion Constructors

    #region Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Tooltip object used to show full path name
    /// </summary>
    private ToolTip Tooltip;

    /// <summary>
    /// Return the full path or just the filename?
    /// </summary>
    [Description("Save Full Path"), Category("Behavior")]
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool SaveFullPath
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// String representing the filename for this control
    /// </summary>
    public override string Text
    {
        get 
        { 
            return base.Text; 
        }
        set 
        {
            if (base.Text != value)
            {
                base.Text = value;
                Tooltip.SetToolTip(this, base.Text);
                Invalidate();
                OnValueChanged(new FileEventArgs(base.Text));
            }
        }
    }

    [Description("Browse Label"), Category("Appearance")]
    [DefaultValue("...")]
    public string BrowseLabel
    {
        get
        {
            return Browse.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            Browse.Text = value;
            Browse.Width = TextRenderer.MeasureText(Browse.Text, Browse.Font).Width + 8;
            Browse.Location = new Point(this.Width - Browse.Width, Browse.Location.Y);
        }
    }

    [Description("Allow Multiple Files"), Category("Behavior")]
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool AllowMultipleFiles
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Selected filename (same as Text property)
    /// </summary>
    [Description("Filename"), Category("Data")]
    public string Filename
    {
        get { return Text; }
        set { Text = value; }
    }
    #endregion Properties

    #region Event Handlers
    /// <summary>
    /// Event raised when 
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler ValueChanged;
    protected virtual void OnValueChanged(FileEventArgs eventargs)
    {
        eventargs.Filename = Filename;
        if (this.ValueChanged != null)
            this.ValueChanged(this, eventargs);
    }

    private void Browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.FileName = Text;

        dlg.Multiselect = AllowMultipleFiles;
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (SaveFullPath)
                Text = dlg.FileName;
            else
                Text = dlg.SafeFileName;
        }
    } 

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // Draw the client window
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(Size.Width-1, Size.Height-1));
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(SystemColors.Window), r);
        g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(VisualStyleInformation.TextControlBorder), r);
        r.Y += Margin.Top;
        r.Width -= Browse.Width;

        // Fill with Text
        TextRenderer.DrawText(g, Text, Font, r, ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.PathEllipsis);

        base.OnPaint(e);
    }

    private void FileTextBox_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        DataObject data = (DataObject)e.Data;
        StringCollection filenames = data.GetFileDropList();

        if ( filenames.Count == 1)
            Text = filenames[0];
    }

    private void FileTextBox_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        DataObject data = (DataObject)e.Data;
        StringCollection filenames = data.GetFileDropList();

        if (/*!AllowMultipleFiles &&*/ filenames.Count == 1)
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Link;
    }
    #endregion Event Handlers

}

public class FileEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public FileEventArgs(string Text)
    {
        Filename = Text;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Name of the file in the control
    /// </summary>
    public String Filename { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That's correct, actually that's my spare approach if this fails.

Comment: Best of luck.  If I think about it when I get to work tomorrow I'll post some sample code from something similar that I've done.